# Which model is better for robot framework implementation?

Tags: robotframework

Currently, I'm implementing a Robot framework using the "Page object model".

Kindly let me know if there is another better model.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the answer depends on what is your system under test (SUT) and how large your test code will be. IMO, page object model is a good choice for SUTs that are systems with many views and you will have a large test automation code base.

If the code base is small, you don't have to think that much about maintainability and code re-usability.